# Misplaced table in UIView after reordering More-TabBarItems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with several UiTabBarItems. Every TabBarItem leads to a NavigationController where the root view contains a UITable that takes the whole screen size.

Let's say the initial order of the TabBarItems is:

"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9"

As long as I leave them in that order everything works very well. But not when I reorder the items in the App by tapping "Edit" in the more tab for example to the following order:

"Item9", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item1"

After reordering the Items, "Item 1" misplaces the UITable in the root view. It seems like above the table has been added a space for a second, not visible NavigationBar.

Does anyone know why or has dealed with the same problem and can tell me what to do to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using xib's for your viewController that is inside the navigation controller? If so open the xib in interface builder and select the main view of controller and in right panel under "Simulated Metrics" set top bar to "Navigation Bar" from dropdown list.

Comment: That pointed me to the right direction.. Thank you so much. That took me so much time...